# adjust Python fuction to parse xml

Tags: python, xml

I need to read an XML file in an external domain.
my code:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.2.57:8010/data/camera_state.xml'))
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag, root.attrib

for elem in tree.iter():
    print elem.tag, elem.att
```

I could not get into the structure I need, the result of my function is this below:

```
CameraState {}
Cameras {}
Camera {'Id': '1'}
State {}
Camera {'Id': '2'}
State {}
Camera {'Id': '3'}
State {}
Camera {'Id': '4'}
State {}
```

I need to adjust this Python function to get into a result as below:

```
<CameraState>
    <Cameras>
        <Camera Id="1">
            <State>NO_SIGNAL</State>
        </Camera>

        <Camera Id="2">
            <State>OK</State>
        </Camera>
    </Cameras>
</CameraState>
```

Comment: can you add an overview of your original XML file, this would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You do have the parsed structure. It's just about the way you are accessing it.

Use `getchildren` to access children nodes. An example of recursively printing the structure:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def print_tree(node, prefix=''):
    print(prefix, node.tag, node.attrib, node.text.strip())
    for child in node:
        print_tree(child, prefix + ' ')


tree = ET.ElementTree(file=<your file>)
root = tree.getroot()

print_tree(root)
```

It gives:

```
CameraState {}
 Cameras {}
  Camera {'Id': '1'}
   State {} NO_SIGNAL
  Camera {'Id': '2'}
   State {} OK
```

However, I recommend you take a look at [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict):

```
import xmltodict


with open(<your file>) as f:
    tree = xmltodict.parse(f.read())

print(tree)
```

It gives you `OrderedDict`s:

```
OrderedDict([('CameraState', OrderedDict([('Cameras', OrderedDict([('Camera', [OrderedDict([('@Id', '1'), ('State', 'NO_SIGNAL')]), OrderedDict([('@Id', '2'), ('State', 'OK')])])]))]))])
```